# how to find next date if it didn't find particular date using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I need help here. I have Sheet 1 and Sheet2. and in Sheet1/2 I have dates in the column B and both sheet dates are not same but when I commend for Select date for print I want VBA to select nearest date if it coudn't find my date. For example:- if I ask VBA to print from date 12-Aug-17 I can be selected in sheet1 but in Sheet 2 there is no 12th Aug so it has to select 13th or 11th and print.
In my coding, if it’s in same date it will print both the sheet. But if it fails then it will show the error.

Please see below my code.

```
Sub nextdate()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim i, j2, j3, sh2EndCell, sh3EndCell As Integer
    Dim W1Enddate As Date

    W1Enddate = Application.InputBox("Enter the End Date")
    ddate = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    sh2EndCell = sh2.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sh3EndCell = sh3.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To sh2EndCell
    If sh2.Range("b" & i).Value = W1Enddate Then
        j2 = i
        Exit For
    End If
```

Comment: First off ddate is not dim to integer in your code. What exactly is ddate used for?

Comment: Date is use for select range by date and print.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your problem description right, but try this:

```
...
...
sh2EndCell = sh2.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim MinDateDiff As Long
Dim ClosestDate

MinDateDiff = 1000000

For i = 2 To sh2EndCell
    If Abs(DateDiff("d", sh2.Range("b" & i).Value, W1Enddate)) < MinDateDiff Then
        MinDateDiff = Abs(DateDiff("d", sh2.Range("b" & i).Value, W1Enddate))
        ClosestDate = sh2.Range("b" & i).Value
        j2 = i
    End If
Next
```